# Is it possible to export a csv file to an SFTP server using Google Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a requirement whereby I need to import a file from an SFTP (Source), perform some basic operations (wrangler) and send it to another SFTP (Target).
So far, I managed to import and transform the file, but when it comes to sending it to the target SFTP I'm not finding a viable/simple solution.
I couldn't find anything related in the documentation.

I was able to find a discussion about that in the link below, but unfortunately, I don't have (and Idk if we will be able to use/access HDFS on Dataproc.

[Some questions about google Data fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752253/some-questions-about-google-data-fusion)

If anyone can shed some light on that it would help a lot!

I tried to use the SFTP Actions, but with no success:

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7a00.png)